# ¿Cómo eliminar contenido de TextBox Asp.Net WebForm con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

Desarrollo una aplicación Asp.Net Web Forms y escribí este código para que el `TextBox` acepte solo números del `0` al `9`, hasta aquí todo bien ahora necesitó que cuando ingrese `0` el contenido del `TextBox` se borre

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Mi TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt00" class="cTxt" runat="server" onkeypress="javascript:return SoloNumeros(event)" MaxLength="1"></asp:TextBox>
```

Mi Código:

```
 <script>
        function SoloNumeros(e) {
            var key;
            if (window.event) 
            {
                key = e.keyCode;
            }
            else if (e.which) 
            {
                key = e.which;
            }
            if (key < 48 || key > 57) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Prueba esta variante:**
`<script>`

```
        function SoloNumeros(e) {
            var key;
            if (window.event) 
            {
                key = e.keyCode;
            }
            else if (e.which) 
            {
                key = e.which;
            }
            if (key > 48 && key < 58) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```